# Trouble configuring vim --with-features=huge

Tags: vim

I cloned the vim source using mercurial, and ran the following commands:

```
make distclean
./configure --with-features=huge
make 
sudo make install
```

The output of all these commands seemed normal.
Yet the output of my vim --version is missing features that should be enabled when `./configure` (`xterm_clipboard`, for example). How can I diagnose this problem? My goal is to enable `netbeans_intg`.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Mar 23 2010 12:50:41)
Included patches: 1-315
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic
+emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path
+float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand
+jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap
+menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte
+multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra +perl +postscript
+printer +profile +python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind
+signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax
+tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse
+textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup
-X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim72"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall  -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1    -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm  -I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE  -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -pthread  -I/opt/local/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
Linking: gcc   -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim       -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lgpm   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DynaLoader/DynaLoader.a -L/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lutil -lc -L/usr/local/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lutil -Xlinker -export-dynamic  -lruby-static -lm
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want that feature and *why* you don't simply install `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk`? Are you on a headless server?

Comment: From the clewn website: "Clewn can only be used with gvim, the graphical implementation of vim, as vim on a terminal does not support netBeans." If you want that feature you must compile Vim with a GUI which you don't. From there, what's the point of building it manually if you can simply install your distrib's `vim-gnome` package?

Comment: Also, the `:version` output in your question is definitely not the expected output if you built Vim from the current sources. You have 7.2.315 built in 2010 instead of 7.3.8something built in 2013. Or are you talking from the past?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're running the vim you built, and not another vim that was already on your system?  In any case, that vim was not built with any GUI (X11) support, as you can see by `Huge version without GUI` in the log.

Including `huge` doesn't get you every feature; it just gets you a lot of them.  If you want X11 and `xterm_clipboard`, make sure you specify an X11 build option.  For a GTK-based system, you can do something like:

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gtk2
```

That will get you most of the X11/graphical features.  If you're not using GTK2, you'll have to specify something else; check out `./configure --help` for a list of features.

You'll need to have various GTK/X11 (or whatever GUI you go with) development libraries installed in order to build with GUI support.  It's possible that it's trying to build with X11 support, but you don't have the right libraries.  Review your `configure` output for errors.

Your OS may have a pre-built binary with all the features you need, as others have suggested, but I've found I always end up having to compile it for one thing or another eventually, so it's worth figuring out.  If you provide more information about the OS you're running (and if OSX, which supplemental package system), someone may have an OS-specific binary package suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have some features enabled in a *huge* build, that's probably due to missing dependencies. The `configure` script runs a lot of detections, and skips certain features when the corresponding libraries or `...-devel` packages are missing. The easiest thing to install those is via

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome # Debian-based
$ sudo yum-builddep vim-gnome # Redhat
```

For the Netbeans integration, romainl is probably right in his remark that that is only available in GVIM (but that should be built with your invocation, too).

Answer (score 2):

`How can I diagnose this problem?`

The way to do it is to *manually*  look back through the `./configure` output, and see what things it couldn't find.  To do this, and because the output isn't really "user friendly",  you got to scroll back and scan the output for lines that end with "no", like:

```
checking if X11 header files can be found... no
```

^ that would signal to you you need to install some sort of X11 devel package etc.

Probably you need GUI support to enable netbeans perhaps?  I see the "without GUI" part in the `Huge version without GUI` part.

Doing that manually requires some effort and trial/error intitially.  Because to actually get it to compile in GUI support, you have to install a bunch of different packages to get all the right development header files  (at least from my personal experience!).  So like people have said, try searching for and installing X11 devel packages, and a gtk2-devel package ^^

(I think at one  point I got frustrated